# S3 subclass constructor with list updating

Tags: r, oop

Imagine that you have an S3 constructor like

```
new_my_class <- function(x, y, ..., subclass = NULL) {
  structure(list(x = x, y = y, ...), class = c(subclass, "my_class"))
}
```

I want to create a subclass of my_class so that the list I use in `structure` is updated with other named elements. For this reason I tried something like

```
new_sub_class <- function(x, y, z) {
  new_my_class(x, y, z, subclass = "sub_class")
}
```

The problem is that in this way I get a list with `z` that doesn't have a name. For instance with

```
new_sub_class(1, 2, 3)
```

I get

> $x
>   [1] 1
>
> $y
>   [1] 2
>
> [[3]]
>   [1] 3
>
> attr(,"class")
>   [1] "sub_class" "my_class"

while I would like to have

> $x
>   [1] 1
>
> $y
>   [1] 2
>
> $z
>   [1] 3
>
> attr(,"class")
>   [1] "sub_class" "my_class"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a name for the third argument, like:

```
new_sub_class <- function(x, y, z) {
  new_my_class(x, y, z=z, subclass = "sub_class")
}

new_sub_class(1, 2, 3)
#$x
#[1] 1
#
#$y
#[1] 2
#
#$z
#[1] 3
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "sub_class" "my_class"
```